# Building a correct graphql introspective query for websocket in json formatting

Tags: json, websocket, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I know that this inquiry is rather newbie in nature, but for the life of me I cannot seem to appropriately perform an instrospection query on a graphql websocket in json. I am assuming that I am querying against an apollo server, because json formatting is required and the websocket server uses graphql structure.

The most basic graphql query should look like:

```
{
  __schema {
    types {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Which should work, but it doesn't in the least. Immediately rejecting the statement for containing the two underscores. So, then I attempt to define a type:

```
{ Query __schema {
  types {
    name
  } 
 }
}
```

Recieving the following error: "Unexpected token Q in JSON at position 2"

So apparently the websocket server wants me to use quotation marks in my query. So I enclose the phrase "query" in parentheses, and this appears to work. But, no matter what I write after that I receive the error of an unexpected token. If I add a colon after the query string like so `"query":` it will reject the colon as well. So at this point, I am completely lost on how to format an introsepction query appropriately.

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why websocket? does it work in playground/normal POST request? test it first

Comment: It is not open to connections through playground, websocket is only available. It is not my server, nor application. Please refer to the github issue I am attempting to troubleshoot. https://github.com/andsala/unsee-dl/issues

Comment: what issue? use API docs/specs ... introspection possibility can be simply blocked/configured as dissalowed